# How to access C# ado.net datatable from VB6?

Tags: c#, vb6, ado.net, vb6-migration

I have one datatable in com component. Can you please guide me how to access the COM component datatable in VB6.

Comment: in vb6 datatable is not available,, so we can use recordset.

Comment: VB6 is going to hate `DataTable`. Basically: don't do that. VB6 doesn't have access to an awful lot of helpful types here - I wonder if your best option is just to pass a string over the boundary. Or, you know, stop using VB6 ;p (although I'm *hoping*, perhaps naively, that this is needed for a "migrate away from VB6" purpose)

Comment: @Thava You need to show the code.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Thanks ,,, I got the answer. i've planned to convert datatable to ADODB.recordset. my classic component i can use the recordset.